# Comments in ET: more than comment tag

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I have a xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Chapter PUBLIC 'blub' 'blub.dtd'>
<Chapter>
    <Tag>
        <TagEntry y.validity.allowed="true" y.validity.mode="positive">
            <!--Kommentar 1-->
            <!--Kommentar 2-->
            <!--Kommentar 3-->Inhalt 1<!--Kommentar 4--></TagEntry>
        <TagEntry>
            Inhalt 2 erg&#228;nzt <!--Kommentar 5-->mit Umlaut
        </TagEntry>
        <TagBase>
            <!--Kommentar 6-->
            <!--Kommentar 7-->Inhalt 3</TagBase>
        <TagNothing>
            Inhalt 3<!--Kommentar 8-->
        </TagNothing>
    </Tag>
</Chapter>
```

Now I want to iterate over the comments.
I did it with lxml.etree as ET-tree:

```
comments = root.xpath('//comment()')
for comment in comments:
    print(ET.tostring(comment))
```

But instead of printing all the comments without the text from the parent node, it prints this:

```
b'<!--Kommentar 1-->'
b'<!--Kommentar 2-->'
b'<!--Kommentar 3-->Inhalt 1'
b'<!--Kommentar 4-->'
b'<!--Kommentar 5-->mit Umlaut\n\t\t'
b'<!--Kommentar 6-->'
b'<!--Kommentar 7-->Inhalt 3'
b'<!--Kommentar 8-->\n\t\t'
```

Can someone explain to me, why this happens and how I can change maybe the xpath-expression to just return the comment nodes without the text being appended to the end of the comment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment nodes are written with the `tail` text included (the default; see https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring).

To get rid of the tails, change

```
print(ET.tostring(comment))
```

to

```
print(ET.tostring(comment, with_tail=False))
```

If you are just interested in the content of the comments and not the markup, use this:

```
print(comment.text)
```